# Open ldap modify - /usr/bin/modify problem

Tags: ldap, openldap

Can anyone help me out on this? I'am trying to add another attribute on my LDAP, but i don't know much about this. It returns an error after trying the sample i searched on net. This command will be used on my perl program to add new attribute "status" w/ value "yes"..

Help pls?

/usr/bin/ldapmodify -x -D "cn=Test,ou=mygroup.com,o=group2.com" -a "status=yes"??

the -W doesn't work too.

Error: ldap_bind: Can't contact LDAP server (-1)

Comment: Is there a way to exclude password?

Answer (score 0):

Try -v for detail log and -w should be in lower case. As for excluding the password one way is to use '-w -' which you will be prompt to enter the password. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the `status` attribute defined in the schema (the attribute cannot be added to an entry unless the entry has an `objectClass` attribute value that allows the `status` attribute). Further, the authentication identity `cn=Test,ou=mygroup.com,o=group2.com` must have permission to add the attribute.

Use `ldapmodify` to add the `status` attribute:

```
ldapmodify -x -D "cn=Test,ou=mygroup.com,o=group2.com" -h hostname -p port <<!
version: 1
dn: uid=user.0,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: status
status: first value
status: second value
!
```

The above example adds two values to the `status` attribute (assuming it is a multi-valued attribute). For more information about the `ldapmodify` tool see ["Using ldapmodify"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/25/master-the-ldapmodify-command-line-tool/).